# Using LINQ to copy data from one list to another

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I have two Lists `public List<string> FileNames` and `public List<string> FileNamesWithoutExtension`. In `FileNames` I have list of all files with full path. I wanted to copy only the filenames without extensions to `FileNamesWithoutExtension` list. I am using below simple code:

```
FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(folderpath, "*").ToList();

foreach (string file in Files)
{
    FileNamesWithoutExtension.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

How to do this using LinQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though what you're doing is absolutely fine, and sometimes (in my opinion) `LINQ` can make a simple loop appear a little more complicated, you can do what you're looking for by using `Select` on the original list, like so:

```
FileNamesWithoutExtensions.AddRange(
    FileNames.Select(fileName => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the .ToList().  `Select` would return an `IEnumerable<>`, which is what the `AddRange` should take.

Comment: Thanks @JamesCurran, I adjusted the snippet to reflect this.

Comment: You can remove the filename => part and just pass the function.